# How do I edit apache .htaccess correctly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

Good day! There are 3 tasks that I want to implement using the .htaccess file:

1. Work only with `https` protocol
2. Create a 301 redirect from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`
3. Redirect all requests to the `index.php` file

My best version of .htaccess looks like this, but I'm not sure if this is the right decision:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

**I would be grateful for any advice!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before you test your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For applying https on each request.
RewriteCond https !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

##For removing www from request.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

##For applying index.php for non existing files or directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```